# Ripple effect and shadow not showing on Raised paper-button in Polymer

Tags: javascript, css, polymer

I'm having trouble showing the ripple effect and the raised shadow on a polymer paper-button (v1.0 of Polymer).

It is showing when I run the demonstration (..bower_components/paper-button/demo/index.html) so all the code must be downloaded. Must be missing either an import or some CSS but cannot spot what is different between the demo page and my site page, or if it is some typo.

My Elements document is

```
<script src='http://www.polymer-project.org/components/platform/platform.js'></script>

<!-- Iron -->
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/iron-icons/iron-icons.html"/>
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/iron-ajax/iron-ajax.html"/>

<!-- Paper Elements -->
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/paper-drawer-panel/paper-drawer-panel.html"/>
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/paper-header-panel/paper-header-panel.html"/>
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/paper-icon-button/paper-icon-button.html"/>
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/paper-input/paper-input.html"/>
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/paper-styles/paper-styles.html"/>
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/paper-toolbar/paper-toolbar.html"/>
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/paper-material/paper-material.html" />
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/paper-behaviors/paper-button-behavior.html" />
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/paper-behaviors/paper-inky-focus-behavior.html" />
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/paper-button/paper-button" />
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/paper-fab/paper-fab.html" />

<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/polymer/polymer.html"/>
```

My Page HTML is as follows

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title>GP and Practice search</title>   <!-- Scripts -->
    <script src="bower_components/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.js"></script>
    <link rel="import" href="elements/elements.html" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Styles/styles.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Styles/home.css"/>
    <!-- google fonts definitions -->
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

</head>

<body unresolved class="fullbleed layout vertical">
    <dom-module id="page-scafolding">
        <template>
            <paper-drawer-panel elevation="1">
                <paper-header-panel main mode="waterfall-tall">
                    <paper-toolbar id="mainToolbar">
                        <paper-icon-button id="paperToggle" icon="menu" paper-drawer-toggle></paper-icon-button>
                        <span class="flex"></span>
                        <paper-icon-button icon="search" on-tap="srchandler" id="srchandler"></paper-icon-button>
                        <input type="text" id="searchText" hidden$="{{hideSearch}}" onkeypress="handleKeyPress(event);" />
                        <div class="middle paper-font-display2 app-name ident">Practice List</div>
                    </paper-toolbar>
                    <paper-material elevation="1">
                        <div id="Content" >
                            <span>
                                <paper-input class="searchBox" label="Search for:"  />
                            </span>
                            <div style="text-align:center; padding:10px;">
                                <paper-button tabindex="0" raised="true" class="colorful" on-click="searchPractice">Search for GP Practice</paper-button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </paper-material>

                </paper-header-panel>
            </paper-drawer-panel>
        </template>
        <script>
            Polymer({
                is: "page-scafolding",
                ready: function () {
                this.hideSearch = true;
                this.$.searchText.keyup(function (e) {
                    alert('off to search for something!');
                });
            },
            srchandler: function () {
                // search for contents of search box is showing, otherwise show it.
                if (!this.hideSearch)
                {
                    alert('off to search for something!');
                }
                else {
                    this.hideSearch = !this.hideSearch;
                    if (!this.hideSearch) {
                        this.$.searchText.focus();
                    }
                }
            },
            searchPractice: function () {
                alert('clicking practice search');
            }
            });
        </script>
    </dom-module>

    <page-scafolding />
</body>
</html>
```

There are two CSS files used by that page

**Home.css**

```
#searchText {
    width:200px;
    border: none;
    line-height: 30px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    background: #3F59B5;
    color: #fff;
    outline: 0;
}

paper-material {
    border-radius: 2px;
    height: 100%;
    padding: 16px 0px 16px 0px;
    width: calc(98.66% - 16px);
    margin: 16px;
    background: white;
}

#Content
{
    padding:16px;
}

paper-button {
    display: block;
    margin-bottom: 24px;
    color: #fff;
    background:#4285F4;
    padding:5px;
    width:175px;
}

paper-button paper-ripple {
      color: var(--paper-pink-a200);
    }
```

and

**Styles.css**

```
body {
    margin:0px;
    background:#e0e0e0;
    font-family:Roboto;
}
```

Can anyone please see where I am going wrong.

Comment: I was also missing the ripple effect (although, the shadow was working). Turns out, I only had Polymer 1.0.0 installed when I needed at least 1.0.4.

Answer (score 0):

Knew I'd missed something - the include for the paper-button was missing it's extension - it should read.

```
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/paper-button/paper-button.html" />
```

in addition the css class for the paper-material was also mucking up the display of the ripple - so that has been changed to a class name.

Removed much of the paper-button class as well meaning I now get a nice blue paper-button

```
.contentContainer {
    border-radius: 2px;
    height: 100%;
    padding: 16px 0px 16px 0px;
    width: calc(98.66% - 16px);
    margin: 16px;
    background: white;
}

#Content
{
    padding:16px;
}

paper-button {
    color: #fff;
    background:#4285F4;
}
```